# while dragging, I don't see helper-lines in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, treeview, drag-and-drop, toolkit

*Silverlight 4, Toolkit*

**During dragging** an item on TARGET CONTROL, there are NOT **visible lines** showing (during mouse move) actual position where will be dragged item put on

*(for example, between items, inside item, before item, …)*

***source control***

```
    <toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="False" AllowedSourceEffects="Copy, Link, Scroll">
      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ToolboxItems}">
             <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate> <!-- some binding --> </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>   
      </ListBox>
   </toolkit:ListBoxDrag...>
```

***target control***

```
<toolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True">
   <sdk:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ScriptRows}"  
     <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
         <!-- some binding -->
     </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:TreeView>
```

*Can somebody help me and say what's wrong ? 
Thank you*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's because the source type MUST be the same interface (type) as TARGET

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't drag&drop inside a TreeView, but both ItemsSource's type are ObservalbeCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem>. Have you any other idea?