# TreeViewDragDropTarget doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, treeview, drag-and-drop

Silverlight, toolkit

I'm using the TreeViewDragDropTarget. Usually, when you drag an item and move it over an another item, the selected item's up-down arrow changes to right arrow.

In my case it won't be changed, and the drag&drop doesn't work.

The TreeView:

```
<controlsToolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget Grid.Row="2" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
    <controlsToolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget.Resources>
        <Data:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FilterableTreeViewTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                <Image Source="{Binding NodeType,Converter={StaticResource TreeIconConverter}}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Data:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </controlsToolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget.Resources>
    <Controls:TreeView Name="treeView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FilterableTreeViewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyFilterableTreeViewControl, Path=ItemsSource}" SelectedItemChanged="treeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>
</controlsToolkit:TreeViewDragDropTarget>
```

The ItemsSource:

```
public ObservableCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem> ItemsSource 
{
    get { return ( ObservableCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem> )GetValue( ItemsSourceProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( ItemsSourceProperty, value ); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "ItemsSource", typeof( ObservableCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem> ), typeof( FilterableTreeViewControl ),
    new PropertyMetadata( null, new PropertyChangedCallback( FilterableTreeViewControl.OnItemsSourcePropertyChange ) ) );

private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChange( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) 
{
    FilterableTreeViewControl ctrl = d as FilterableTreeViewControl;
            ctrl.OnItemsSourceChange( ( ObservableCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem> )e.NewValue );
}

protected virtual void OnItemsSourceChange( ObservableCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem> NewItemsSource ) 
{
    UpdateTreeViewItemsSource( NewItemsSource );
}
```

Any idea?

---

If I remove the ItemTemplate, than "works".

---

I've found that [while dragging, I don't see helper-lines in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286522/while-dragging-i-dont-see-helper-lines-in-silverlight)

But in my case these two type are the same: `ObservableCollection<IFilterableTreeViewItem>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the solution:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/HierarchicalDataTemplate.aspx

I needed one more TreeNode abstraction level.